# How to (correctly) loop in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm using XSLT to process an XML file and I'm having an error while looping through elements.

This is a snapshot of my XML file

```
<pl__pl_nc_name>
      <pl_nc_name_literal type="text_oneline">Value1</pl_nc_name_literal>
</pl__pl_nc_name>

...

<pl__pl_nc_name>
      <pl_nc_name_literal type="text_oneline">Value2</pl_nc_name_literal>
</pl__pl_nc_name>
```

To loop over `<pl__pl_nc_name>` I used `for-each`

```
 <plIdentifier_name_literal>
        <xsl:for-each select="pr:_nested__pl__pl_nc_name/pr:pl__pl_nc_name">
            <xsl:value-of select="pr:pl_nc_name_literal"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
 </plIdentifier_name_literal>
```

However, as output I'm having one element with the two values

```
<plIdentifier_name_literal>Value1Value2</plIdentifier_name_literal>
```

Instead I would like to have

```
<plIdentifier_name_literal>Value1</plIdentifier_name_literal>
<plIdentifier_name_literal>Value2</plIdentifier_name_literal>
```

I tried to add the `@` before the `pl_nc_name_literal` like `@pl_nc_name_literal` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an element for each node, you must create the element within the `xsl:for-each` instruction:

```
<xsl:for-each select="pr:_nested__pl__pl_nc_name/pr:pl__pl_nc_name">
    <plIdentifier_name_literal>
        <xsl:value-of select="pr:pl_nc_name_literal"/>
    </plIdentifier_name_literal>
</xsl:for-each>
```

---

P.S. `xsl:for-each` is not a "loop".